Why am I seeing so many Staging Ground questions with ignored tags?
Before Staging Ground launched today, I almost never saw questions with ignored tags on my front page (usually only when I had added the tags to the question myself), but now I'm seeing them all the time.
Is this on purpose? If so, why?

(I have some userstyles active, if you're wondering why it looks like that.)

You mean you are seeing questions which have tags that are on your ignored tag list. I was looking for a tag "ignored" in that screenshot of yours wondering what it's purpose was :)

@Gimby Tags on the ignored tag list are called "ignored tags". If I wanted to refer to a tag called "ignored", I would say "the ignored tag". But yes, that's what I'm talking about and if it helps clarify the question, I appreciate your comment.

To answer your question - this was not on purpose! As far as I can tell, we mistakenly did not respect a user's ignored tags when showing Staging Ground posts on the questions page. I've implemented a simple method that filters out posts with ignored tags before we populate them into the question list. This will be live either today or tomorrow, so after tomorrow, if you're still seeing any quirks, please let me know so that I can address them. Thank you for the report!
